# Css custom properties not working in webhosting

Tags: css, web, properties, hosting

would need some help regarding a CSS custom properties issue.

I've recently brought a webhosting service from Hostinger, and is using the default Wordpress template.

Our web designer have created a website in teleporthq.io, and have exported the files out as htmls and CSS.

I've deleted the entire public_html folder, and created a empty public_html folder, and placed all the exported files into it, with the main page being index.html

While I'm able to load the page, the style of the webpage is out of place. Upon closer inspection, the CSS Custom Properties are all not loading, thus making the webpage looks wrong.

When opening the webpages locally, I can see that the page is displaying correctly, thus making me thinks that it may be a setting(or application deployed?) in the webhosting that I've missed out.

[This is the error  that I observe at the css file while editing on the web word editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21M3X.png):
*Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 3.*

[While in the place that uses the custom property, this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsDFh.png):
*Expected (<color> | inherit) but found 'var(--dl-color-gray-black)'.*

Anyone have any insight as to what I would need to do to enable CSS Custom Properties on a webhosting?(in my case, Hostinger)

```
:root {  --dl-color-gray-500: #595959; } 
.input { color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
         cursor: auto;  
         padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
         font-family: Inter;   
         border-color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);   
         border-width: 1px;   
         border-radius: 4px;   
         background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white); 
 }
```

Comment: Can you post here your relevant css code?

Comment: The snippet of the css:

`:root {
  --dl-color-gray-500: #595959;
}`

The place using the css:

`.input {
  color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-family: Inter;
  border-color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);
}`

Comment: ill add this code into the question, for the next time, modify your question and don't add code into comments please .

Answer (score 0):

Weird, have you tested in different servers to make sure is the hosting? I would do that first and test the css properties on other elements. Also, use codepen or jsfiddle to double-check your code works.